# When viewing last page of a Saves list and it has one item only, the filter tabs disappear

Tags: bug, design, pagination, saves

There appears to be an edge case bug whereby the tabs of a Saves list disappear from view, namely the "Score | Activity | Views | Newest | Added" tabs.

[image: the filter tabs]

This happens when you have `( n mod 30 ) == 1` items in a Saves list, namely a multiple of the pagination length plus one (1, 31, 61, 91, 121, 151, 181, etc.), and you are viewing the last page of the Saves list. In other words, when you only have one post displayed on a Saves list page.

[image: screenshot showing the bug where there is one item in the last page and no filters]

I guess that a decision was made to hide the tabs when there was only one item in the Saves list, and this is probably OK and I have no comment to make about that:

[image: case where the list itself has only one item and thus no filters is correct]

Normally, clicking on one of the tabs when they are visible refreshes the page and presents you with the first page of your Saves list in the new sorted order:

[image: pagination buttons]

However, clicking on one of the tabs is not possible when you have, for example, exactly 91 or 181 items (these numbers have been tested) in a Saves list and you are viewing the last page, because the tabs have disappeared.