# Changing the sort order in the “Saves” tab does not update the view

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, saves

Changing the sort order in the “Saves” tab in the user profile does not update the view anymore. Only after a browser refresh are the saves displayed according to the newly selected order.

This happens on all sites tested so far ([Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), Stack Overflow, and [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)).

It was first noticed with rev 2024.3.1.5619 of the site software and was tested with:

- [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) 17.3.1, Firefox 123, and Google Chrome 122, on [macOS 14.3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sonoma) (Sonoma),
- Mobile Safari on [iOS 17.3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_17) on an [iPhone SE 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_SE_(2nd_generation)).

Comment: Do you remember if this worked before?

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda: I am fairly sure that it worked before. And it does work at other places, e.g. in the Questions/Answers/Following tabs of the user profile: clicking on Score/Activity/Newest immediately updates the view.

Comment: Yeah, there was a recent bug fix, related to Saves, so most likely it's the cause for the bug here. I've left a comment on the developer's answer there.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda I am sure it worked before as I documented a [bug here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395639/1242908) where I specifically mentioned: "Normally, clicking on one of the tabs when they are visible refreshes the page and presents you with the first page of your Saves list in the new sorted order:"

Comment: Looks like I may have broken this, going to look into it today and report back. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: I definitely did break it! I've got a fix in the works and will post details below once it's approved and merged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got a fix pushed that should be live today or tomorrow. I fixed [the other bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382690/344828) by adding back in some js that the Saves tab didn't have. However, that js also tries to run the Save sorts through the same route as the other tabs. Because the Saves feature is much newer, it was implemented separately from the other tabs... but still had some of the same classes in the sorting button group as the other tabs. The fix, once I figured it out, was super easy - just had to remove those classes.

I am *fairly certain* I haven't broken anything else but, famous last words and all. Please let me know if you continue to see any issues, thanks for your patience, and thanks for reporting!

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda it should be live now!

Comment: It is! Which is odd, as the footer says `rev 2024.3.5.5754` i.e. last update was yesterday when it still didn't work. Unless the rev is for "code behind" only, not client side?

Comment: Yes, it works now, thanks for fixing it! – There is still a different behavior compared to sort selectors at other places (questions, answers). Changing the sort order makes the page jump to the top and (apparently) reloads the entire page.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, that's a difference in behavior due to the way that page was implemented compared to the others. Work required to change that is well beyond a bug fix, unfortunately!

Answer (score 6):

After digging into it, I believe I've found the probable cause, but sadly I can't fix or suggest a workaround.

When changing the sort order in the answers or questions tabs of the profile (which works fine), there's an AJAX request sent to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/ajax/users/tab`, followed by the user id, and giving which tab and what is the desired sort. E.g., the full URL would be `https://meta.stackexchange.com/ajax/users/tab/152859?tab=answers&sort=activity`. (There isn't any point in going there; first change the user id to be yours.)

So, what happens when trying to do it for Saves? This is the URL being requested: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/ajax/users/tab/152859?sort=Activity`. As you might notice, the "tab" parameter is missing, so the code behind doesn't know what data to pull, hence throwing *404 Not Found* error.

I did try to manually add `tab=Saves`, `tab=Bookmarks`, and `tab=Favorites` but none works. It appears to require a change in the [code-behind](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code-behind#Noun) itself to support the rather-new *Saves*.

Answer (score 2):

A simple but not very elegant workaround would be to right mouse click on one of the sort tabs and then select "Open link in new tab" (for Chrome, for example). This works on Windows desktop and also on Android (but it is a little fiddly on Android).

[image: click on a sort tab and then select open link in new tab]

Alternatively, left mouse click on one of the sort tabs which changes the URL, but then you need to click the browser refresh button to get the new sort order to display.

[image: click on a sort tab and then click the browser refresh button]